# Called intention with screen off

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, foreground-service

I am writing an application that has a ForegroundService that listens for bluetooth events. When the event occurs, it is supposed to open an intent, regardless of the state of the device. Unfortunately it doesn't work when the phone is in the off screen state - in Logcat I can see that onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() have been called, but immediately afterwards onPause() is called and the intention is not even displayed. minSdk=24. I have tried various methods and flags, to no avail.

In the manifest file I have the permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINODW.

The code to open the intent looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(btForegroundService.this, emergency.class);
                                
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                         
       startActivity(intent);
```

The start of the onCreate()method looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        Log.i("EMERGENCY" ,"onCreate called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_alert);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27){
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            if(keyguardManager!=null)
                keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);

        } else {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        }

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Is there any way to solve this?  Thank you for any help

Comment: Android's [PowerManager] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager) gives you the control you need over aspects of the device's power state.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you say a bit more? Why is it needed to display intentions on the lock screen?